# How in php extensions get access to http header

Tags: php, c++, c, php-extension

I am writing PHP extensions in C/C++ and I need to get access (read only) to http header which is send with the request. I tryied SAPI but I failed. :(

Is there is any portable solution (with working source code)?

Comment: Hello, could you please show us what you've already try ? Please explain why did you fail when you've tried SAPI.

Comment: I failed because of:


php_printf("SAPI! %s <br/>", zend_llist_get_first(&SG(sapi_headers).headers));


and I got result:

SAPI! ř/oÍ#

I also tried to get to the $_SERVER variable but none of solution which I found isn't working unter PHP 5.4

Comment: `zend_llist_get_first()` returns an opaque `void*` pointer, pointing to a struct that is stored in the list; in the case of sapi headers this is a `sapi_header_struct`. Hence, you need to cast first, and then additionally access `sapi_header_struct::header` - see my answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620354/how-in-php-extensions-get-access-to-http-header/19616228#19616228)

Answer (score 2):

This is the way you can traverse the list of http headers and output each:

```
zend_llist_position pos;
sapi_header_struct* h;
for (h = (sapi_header_struct*)zend_llist_get_first_ex(&SG(sapi_headers).headers, &pos);
     h;
     h = (sapi_header_struct*)zend_llist_get_next_ex(&SG(sapi_headers).headers, &pos))
{
    php_printf("SAPI! %.*s <br/>", h->header_len, h->header);
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the above example. However for me it only produces one header: X-Powered-By. I've confirmed the size of the list is 1 by using the zend_llist_count. At the same time the $_SERVER[] contains the usual set of HTTP headers (more than 1). Have I overlooked something?